# How can I generate random integers in a range in Smalltalk?

Tags: random, smalltalk, logical-operators

A class I am taking currently requires us to do all of our coding in smalltalk (it's a Design class). On one of our projects, I am looking to do some things, and am having a tough time finding how to do them. It seems that what most people do is modify their own version of smalltalk to do what they need it to do. I am not at liberty to do this, as this would cause an error on my prof's computer when he doesn't have the same built-in methods I do.

Here's what I'm looking to do:

Random Numbers. I need to create a random number between 1 and 1000. Right now I'm faking it by doing

```
rand := Random new.
rand := (rand nextValue) * 1000.
rand := rand asInteger.
```

This gives me a number between 0 and 1000. Is there a way to do this in one command? similar to

```
Random between: 0 and: 1000
```

And/Or statements. This one bugs the living daylights out of me. I have tried several different configurations of

```
(statement) and: (statement) ifTrue...
(statement) and (statement) ifTrue...
```

So I'm faking it with nested ifTrue statements:

```
(statement) ifTrue:[
    (statement) ifTrue:[...
```

What is the correct way to do and/or and Random in smalltalk?

Comment: It would be useful to separate out the two different questions into two separate pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
 (expr) and: (expr) ifTrue: aBlock
```

is parsed as the method `and:ifTrue:`  If you look at the Boolean class (and either True or False in particular), you notice that ifTrue: is just a regular method, and that no method and:ifTrue: exists - however, plain and: does. So to make it clear that these are two messages, write

```
((expr) and: (expr)) ifTrue: aBlock
```

For longer boolean combinations, notice that there are also methods and:and: and and:and:and: implemented.

Comment: But that's incomplete since and: takes a block, as said by rydier. And and without the column would be parsed as a unary message and cause a parse error afterwards because it only expects messages after it, not a full expression.

Answer (score 6):

```
(1 to: 1000) atRandom
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using VisualWorks, and: takes a block as an argument, so you'd write:

```
(aBoolean and: [anotherBoolean]) ifTrue: [doSomething].
```

There's also `&`, which does not take a block as argument,

```
aBoolean & anotherBoolean ifTrue:[doSomething].
```

The difference is and: only evaluates what's in the block if the first bool is true (similar to java), while `&` always evaluates both.

Thus `and:` comes in handy if the second condition is computationally expensive, or if it includes state alterations which should only happen when the first condition is true. (that's usually a bad design though).

As for the Random, as long as you deliver your custom method, `Random >> between: and:` as well as the rest of your code, it runs fine on your professors computer. How to do that specifically, depends on the format in which you are supposed to deliver the assignment.

Answer (score 4):

As for the Random issue: it depends on what ST version you use. In Squeak 3.9, there is `Random>>#nextInt:`, which is documented as "Answer a random integer in the interval [1, anInteger].". Its implementation reads

```
(self next * anInteger) truncated + 1
```

So I have two comments here:

1. You should really learn to use the class browser. This can answer the (frequent) questions "what messages can I send to objects of class X"
2. It is common, in ST, to add new methods to existing classes. So if you want Random to have between:and:, just add it, e.g. as

   ```
   between: low and: high      
      ^(self next * (high-low+1)) truncated + low
   ```

Comment: well, thats the thing. We're not using Squeak at all. The version we're using only has next and nextValue.

Comment: Still, you can add any new methods that you find useful.

Comment: The mechanism Martin is referring to is named class extensions. Basically you can define a method on a class that was defined elsewhere, and still have that method packaged with the rest of your code, be it in a fileout or a commit. The way to do it exactly depends on the dialect, but you still haven't told us which one you're using...

Answer (score 0):

**To create several random integers between 1 and 1000**
First create a random number series.  Do this just once.

Then create a new random number by taking the next number from the series.   Repeat as necessary.

```
aRandomSeries := Random new .
    "Seed a new series of random numbers"  

aRandomInt := aRandomSeries newInt: 1000 . 
    "generate a random integer between 0 and 1000"

anotherRandomInt := aRandomSeries newInt: 1000 .
    "generate another random integer between 0 and 1000"
```

**Logical operations**

`aBoolean` will respond to `and:` and `or:`.  They both take *block arguments*.

Here is how they work.

`and: alternativeBlock`
If the receiver is true, answer the value of alternativeBlock; otherwise answer false without evaluating alternativeBlock.

`or: alternativeBlock`
If the receiver is false, answer the value of alternativeBlock; otherwise answer true without evaluating alternativeBlock.

e.g.
`( 3 > 2 ) or: [ 3 < 4 ] ifTrue: [ ]`
`aBoolean and: [ anotherBoolean ] ifFalse: [ ]`

However, Squeak and Pharo Smalltalks will both accept an argument in parentheses `( )`
Dolphin Smalltalk will not, and strictly requires the standard Smalltalk syntax of a block argument.

**Other related methods:**
`&` an *AND* that does not require a square bracketted (i.e. block) argument
`|` an *OR* that does not require a square bracketted (i.e. block) argument
`&` and `|` work in Amber, Cuis, Gnu, Pharo, Squeak, VisualAge and VisualWorks Smalltalks.

Squeak Smalltalk also provides:
`and:and:          }`
`and:and:and:      }`   These take multiple block arguments
`and:and:and:and   }`

`or:or:           }`
`or:or:or:        }`   These take multiple block arguments
`or:or:or:or:     }`

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, without knowing the Smalltalk dialect, I can only give a general answer. The way you stated the random question, yes that's the only way to do it if your professor needs a generic answer.

As for the and/or statements question,

> And/Or statements. This one bugs the living daylights out of me. I have tried several different configurations of

```
(statement) and: (statement) ifTrue...
(statement) and (statement) ifTrue...
```

What you want to try is:

```
(statement) and: [statement] ifTrue: [ ... ]
```

note the brackets, the and: method takes a block as an argument.